# SQLite Database with default value

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, cordova

I use a sqlite database for a phonegap app.

I try something like this:

Create the tabel at the first time app start:

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SETTINGS (id unique,data)');
```

after that i will get the first row item:

```
var returnwert = results.rows.item(0).data;
```

That code will produce the following error:

```
Item index is out of range!
```

I know why, because its no default value in the table.

How can i create a table with a dafult value?

Something like that:

```
 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SETTINGS (id unique 1, 2, 3,data defaultvalue="test")');
```

A table named SETTINGS with 3 rows likt this:

```
id = 0 data = test
id = 1 data = test
id = 2 data = test
```

Can someone may help me

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` syntax is invalid

Comment: @mpears: check my updated answer, it should work for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant something like this to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    data VARCHAR(128)
)
```

To populate table with some values, use these statements:

```
REPLACE INTO settings VALUES (1, 'test');
REPLACE INTO settings VALUES (2, 'test');
REPLACE INTO settings VALUES (3, 'test');
```

If you run it for first time, rows for id 1,2,3 will be created.

If you run it for second time, rows for id 1,2,3 will be overwritten.

If you do not want to overwrite, use `INSERT OR IGNORE` like this:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO settings VALUES (1, 'test');
...
```

Comment: does sqlite accept "VARCHAR" ? latest time i test it, it wasn't work with forced me to make it "TEXT"

Comment: As strange as it sounds, but SQLite will accept anything for type. It type contains `INT`, it will treat it as integer. It if contains `CHAR` or `TEXT`, it will treat it as text. There are more rules, read [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: The problem is i won't like to overwrite if the table exists.

Comment: 1. First time the app starts on a phone... create table set default value... 2. Set new values to the table 3. Second start of the app the new values (set in step 2.) should not be overwritten!

Comment: did u test it on a real device ?

Comment: @mpears: I updated answer to mention `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` clause

Comment: `tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SETTINGS (id unique, data);', null, function() {
    alert("SUCCESS");
   }, function() {
    alert("FAIL");
   });tx.executeSql('INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE INTO SETTINGS VALUES (1, "test")');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE INTO SETTINGS VALUES (2, "test")');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE INTO SETTINGS VALUES (3, "test")');` got the error undefined

Comment: Weird, SQLite doc mentions that [ON CONFLICT should work](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) and it does not. I checked that `INSERT OR IGNORE` does work (answer updated). Also, please use correct syntax for `CREATE TABLE`: you must specify types - you didn't (in which case it will use same type as BLOB).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the creation of your sqlite tables.

```
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE "SETTINGS" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT    NULL , "DATA" TEXT NOT NULL);',
                  null,
                  function(){/* to do on success */},
                  function(){/* to do on fail */}
);
```

Then on insert you should use this query:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO \"book\" VALUES(1,'test');",null,function(){/* to do on success */},function(){/* to do on fail */});
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO \"book\" VALUES(2,'test');",null,function(){/* to do on success */},function(){/* to do on fail */});
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO \"book\" VALUES(3,'test');",null,function(){/* to do on success */},function(){/* to do on fail */});
```

You can always refer to the [phonegap documentary](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code to open a new database, insert and read values from it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Query the database
    //
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
  console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
  // this will be true since it was a select statement and so rowsAffected was 0
  if (!results.rowsAffected) {
    console.log('No rows affected!');
    return false;
  }
  // for an insert statement, this property will return the ID of the last inserted row
  console.log("Last inserted row ID = " + results.insertId);
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```